# how to add a node_modules .css file to the ionic 3 build?

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, build

In the latest version of ionic (3.0.1) and ionic-app-scripts (1.3.0), how can you add or import js vanilla and simple css files to the ionic build?

```
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
Node Version: v7.4.0
```